# Dynamic subdomain creation in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create dynamically subdomain in wp. I want to run my complete site on subdomain. As example my site is www.domain.com and i want to run complete site on subdomain.domain.com. 
I have added 'A' record in cpanel that redirects me to subdomain. But when click on menu it redirects to domain.com its because of the link which is saved in database. I want to append subdomain name on each link which is retrieved from the database. There may be many user so i don't want to create static subdomain in cpanel.

Can we use .htaccess file for that or any have other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, You would have to change the domain saved in DB with the new domain.

Just take a MySQL DB dump and find and replace all occurances of http://www.domain.com with http://subdomain.domain.com

Once that is done, import it (please take a backup first).

Everything *should* work out.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No i want to create dynamic subdomain. if i will change in database, it would be static. I have different user and user name would be the subdomain name.

Comment: There is no such thing as "dynamic" sub domain, as far as I know. If you really want your wordpress to be available at both domain.com and subdomain.domain.com, then the only possible way, as I see it, would be to have 2 wordpress instances installed and 2 Vhosts created in your server and 2 databases and everything will be x2.